# AWS S3 Policy for authenticated users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl, bucket

I'm trying to set a S3 Policy bucket but it does not work at all. I need to allow to upload files to anonymous users but only authenticated users can download those. I tried 2 thinks:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1378380575437",
  "Statement": [
{
  "Sid": "Stmt1378380436712",
  "Action": [
    "s3:PutObject"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
      "*"
    ]
  }
},
{
  "Sid": "Stmt1378380568645",
  "Action": [
    "s3:GetObject"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
      "arn:aws:iam::1111111111:root"
    ]
  }
 }
 ]
}
```

But the problem is the GetObject is allowed by default, then it means anonymous users can download files. I tried to add a new Sid denying for * the GetObject but denies always override allows.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this with ACLs. Change the permissions on your bucket to requiring ACL 'authenticated-read'. Your users will have to set that ACL flag on their uploads or they'll get an accessed denied error, but if you can get them to set that flag I think this may work for you. 
[Editing Bucket Permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingBucketPermissions.html)

Comment: I need sort of the opposite to this. I need that a user is only allowed to download the resource if logged in to my website. I think I can do this using a public-read acl but this means that anyone with the link can download the resource, whether or not they are signed into the website. However, I want that only those logged in can download the file. Is an abstraction of this sort possible?